# How to resolve "'std::length_error" while passing class member string to other class function?

Tags: c++, string, event-handling

I have following classes,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class eventHadler
{
  public:
  virtual void online(string& str)
   {
   cout<<" str :"<< str << endl;  // accessing str here in this function caused "std::length_error"
   }
};
```

and the event generator class is as follows:

```
class my
{
   public:
   eventHadler *ptr; // this is initialized in one member function
   string localStr;
   my()
   {
        localStr.reserve(1);
        ptr = NULL;
    }
   static void myfun(void* pt);
};

    void my::myfun(void* ptMy)
    {
        my *hdl = static_cast < my* >(ptMy);
        hdl->localStr.clear();
        hdl->localStr.append("mtfun called");
        hdl->ptr->online(hdl->localStr);
    }


int main()
{
        eventHadler eventobj;
        my myObj;
        myObj.ptr = &eventobj;
        my::myfun((void*)&myObj);
        return 0;
}
```

But with the call to `my::myfun()`,  passing localStr to `online()` function causes following

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_create
```

I'm not able to reproduce above error but it occurs in my development code.

Any pointer to resolve this error.

P.S: I can't change `myfun()` prototype.

Comment: `eventHaldler` does not have a member called `localStr`.

Comment: @juanchopanza : corrected the code , please check now, sorry!

Comment: Post some code that compiles.

Answer (score 0):

You probably try to create a string with negative length.

Comment: I created string only once with reserved space. No chance to create a string with negative length.